# jQuery 1.3.2 - Best way to prevent events triggering on lower elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this (simplification):

```
$(li).click(function{alert("test");});

<li>
   <input>
</li>
```

What's the best way to bind an event to `li` but not fire when the user clicks on the `input` element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method on the Event object.

```
$('input').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You could also target specific children (or direct children) of `li` using a combination of selectors:

```
$('li > input, li strong, li span').click( ... );
```

Comment: I knew my solution was bad ;)

Answer (score 2):

One solution could involve using `event.target`.

In the event handler, use

```
if( $(event.target).is('input') )
    return;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to manually filter it.

```
$(li).click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is("input")) {
        alert("Test");
    }
});
```